# Google Sheets formula that returns all values for which multiple criteria in other columns apply

Tags: google-sheets

**My problem, generally stated:**

I need a formula that returns all the values in a specific column for which multiple criteria in other columns of the respective row apply.

**My problem, specifically stated:**

I would like a formula that returns all the values in Column A for which Column C is "John", Column E is "Apples", Column G is "Earth" and both Columns H and I are empty. See [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aR1dmdgWxKog27YuZytIrKzfTU7rHtuuTEi9Kc7w_24/edit?usp=sharing) for a simplified illustration of my problem with dummy data. The correct formula, dragged down, would output a list with the values "1", "4", and "14". If you'd like to try out some stuff in the linked spreadsheet, feel free to do so in a copy of the original sheet so others can see my original data/formulas.

**What I've tried so far:**

Simply filtering was not an option because the data is on a separate sheet within the same spreadsheet. I also knew VLOOKUP and INDEX/MATCH were not going to do what I wanted - VLOOKUP doesn't handle multiple criteria, and while the MATCH part of INDEX/MATCH can be turned into an array to specify multiple criteria, it only returns the first value for which all conditions are true, while I need all of them.

I then tried the following formula (Formula 1 in the linked spreadsheet):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$I, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($K$2, $C$2:$C)*COUNTIF($K$3, $E$2:$E)*COUNTIF($K$4, $G$2:$G), ROW($A$2:$I)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$I))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),"")
```

It worked like a charm, until I wanted to include the condition that both columns H and I should be empty. I tried this, but for some reason I don't understand it didn't work (Formula 2 in the linked spreadsheet):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$I, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($K$2, $C$2:$C)*COUNTIF($K$3, $E$2:$E)*COUNTIF($K$4, $G$2:$G)*COUNTIF($K$5, $H$2:$H)*COUNTIF($K$6, $I$2:$I), ROW($A$2:$I)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$I))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),"")
```

Then I tried to nest my first formula into an IF/VLOOKUP (Formula 3 in the linked spreadsheet):

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(INDEX($A$2:$I, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($K$2, $C$2:$C)*COUNTIF($K$3, $E$2:$E)*COUNTIF($K$4, $G$2:$G), ROW($A$2:$I)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$I))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),$A$2:I,8,FALSE)<>"","",INDEX($A$2:$I, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($K$2, $C$2:$C)*COUNTIF($K$3, $E$2:$E)*COUNTIF($K$4, $G$2:$G), ROW($A$2:$I)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$I))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1))),"")
```

This worked if I only asked for column H to be empty, but a) it is very unwieldy, b) it gives you blanks in the list it returns, which I do not want, and c) I could not get it to work for the condition that both columns H and I need to be empty using OR.

That's where I'm stuck, and I haven't come up with a good solution. Knowing this forum, I'm sure someone has an elegant solution I was not smart enough to find :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm on phone so formating will suffer.

Create a new column on the left and insert the following into cell A2

```
    =if(D2="John", if(F2="Apples", if(H2="Earth", if(I2="", if(J2="", B2,""), "" ), "" ), "" ), "")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried what you suggested, but the problem is I can't have blanks between the filtered values. I guess I could try working around this with an additional column and SORT/UNIQUE, but there must be another way?

Comment: Then once you apply the formula, sort by column A depending.

Comment: You mean descending? The output is on a different sheet than the data though (the user will never see the sheet the data is on). So in order to use your solution, I would have to put your formula on the output sheet, replicating column A from the data sheet with blanks in it, in a hidden column, and then do a SORT/UNIQUE on that column in the place where I want the filtered values to be. That's a bit complicated, but it does the job - will use this until someone suggests a better solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, descending (phone autocorrect).  If you want to show the data in another sheet (with no blank cells) you can use a sort(array formula like this      `=sort(arrayformula(Sheet1!A2:A15))`